# How to make an image move while growing?

Tags: xcode5

The image in this code grows from the center until it reaches its final size and then stops. What I need is to also make the image move to the bottom center while it's growing. 
Thank you.

```
- (IBAction)expand:(id)sender {


    grow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.7];
    grow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5, 5);

        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

        grow.alpha = 1.0;


        [UIView commitAnimations];


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer and it works for me. I added this after my first code and got the desired effect. Here is the code:

grow.center = CGPointMake(150, 650);

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                 animations:^{grow.center= CGPointMake(160, 244);}];
```

I had to turn Autolayout off for this to work properly.

Thank you Xono again for your answer and replies :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to tackle this. The animation code technique you're using was replaced in iOS4, and the use of CGAffineTransform is (to my tastes) not exactly ideal either.

Nonetheless, if you wanted to use this approach, you could do something similar to this (note: I haven't tested this, it's more or less a best guess):

```
- (IBAction)expand:(id)sender {
   grow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
   CGFloat scale = 5.0;
   CGFloat moveDistance = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - (grow.frame.origin.y*scale)) - grow.frame.origin.y;
   CGAffineTransform transformation = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
   transformation = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transformation, 0, moveDistance);
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.7];
       grow.transform = transformation;
       [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        grow.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I would recommend though looking into the use of block-based animation methods though - it's a lot simpler and more readable. Also, the use of CGAffineTransform for scaling up can occasionally cause problems (for example, if you increase the size of a UILabel's frame, it simply repositions the text. If you use CGAffineTransform, the text zooms in, becoming pixellated). You could do something similar to this:

```
CGFloat scale = 5.0;
CGRect originalFrame = grow.frame;
CGRect targetFrame = CGRectMake(
    originalFrame.origin.x-(originalFrame.size.width*(scale/2.0)),
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - (originalFrame.size.height*scale),
    originalFrame.size.width*scale, 
    originalFrame.size.height*scale);
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.7 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1]
    grow.frame = targetFrame;
    grow.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: First, thank you so much for taking the bother to answer my question. I didn't even expect such a fast reply so thank you for that too. Well, I tried the first lines of codes but got two errors: 1- Too many arguments to function call, expected 2, have 3.
2- Too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2.              The other codes had some weird animation like grow then shrink and move away from the view and so.

Comment: Just quickly make sure it is the most recent code - I edited it a couple of times, and one of the mistakes I edited was passing a parameter to the wrong method (`CGAffineTransformMakeScale` should have 2 parameters, `CGAffineTransformTranslate` should have 3). The second block of code should work much the same as the first, including autoreverse (so yes, grow, then shrink). Did you also want the movement to autoreverse?

Comment: Now the first one works but the image keeps moving towards the bottom until it completely disappears. What I exactly want is that the image stops when its upper half is still visible and the other half disappears and that when it reaches its biggest size.

Comment: In that case, try reversing the order of the transform commands - so use `CGAffineTransform transformation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, moveDistance);` then `transformation = CGAffineTransformScale(transformation, scale, scale)`. Somehow I always get the order of those mixed up.

Comment: The thing here is that CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation requires three parameters and CGAffineTransformScale requires two so the way you specified produces errors.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd see errors, cause that is definitely incorrect.  The method `CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation ( CGFloat tx, CGFloat ty )` clearly takes two parameters, as specified in Apple's docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html . The lines I mentioned in my comment also build fine in Xcode. Make sure you're using CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation and not CGAffineTransformTranslate.